# C++ thread safe string wrapper

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hello i am writing thread safe wrapper for std::string

```
class ThreadSafeString
{
public:
    ThreadSafeString(std::string&& str) noexcept
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock(mutexString);
        buffer = std::move(str);
    }

private:
    std::string buffer;
    std::mutex mutexString;
};
```

constructor is marked with warning:

> ```
> warning C26111: Caller failing to release lock <lock> before calling function <func>.
> ```

1. what is caller and what is calling function? i dont call any function with same mutex in ctor.
2. is my wrapper thread safe? what is better way do thread safe string if i need copy/move ctor/operator=()

Comment: First hit on a search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26111?view=msvc-160. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read[ask]. BTW: There is also codereview.stackexchange.com for code review questions.

Comment: _"... i dont call any function ..."_ `buffer = std::move(str);` calls the `std::string` move assignment operator (method/funcion).

Comment: i dont call any function WITH SAME MUTEX

Comment: This is not a [mcve], the above code compiled alone does not (I believe) generate that warning.  Srcond, locking that mutex in constructor is pointless; until constructor returns, sharing this between threads is insanity.

Comment: @vova It's warning you that you are calling a function with the mutex still held.  In this case that is what you want to do; so the warning for you is a false positive.  In general though calling a function (that might do anything) is not a good idea whilst holding a lock.    The 5 digit warning codes come from the MSVC Static Analyser (not the compiler itself) and may give false positives.

Comment: @Richard Critten here should be mutex because this class can contain 10 methods which modify buffer string from 10 other threads. And one thread should not replace string in ctor when 10 other thread work with that. Is my solution good for this situation?

Comment: How would those 10 threads get a reference or a pointer to a `ThreadSafeString` object **before** that object even got constructed? If you managed to do that, then you likely have undefined behavior, mutex or no mutex. The phrase "replace string in constructor" doesn't make sense - the object doesn't exist until the constructor is finished, there's nothing to be replaced. Are you thinking of an assignment operator, perhaps?